# Qt Research/Academic/Journal Papers/Articles

Tags: qt, real-time, safety-critical

I'm trying to find any research/academic/journal papers/articles that analyze recent versions of Qt and Qt Creator.

Specifically, I'm trying to evaluate Qt from a real-time safety critical perspective, so any information is helpful.

P.S.  I've tried the typical search approach:
Google scholar, IEEE Explore, ACM Digital Libray, etc.
Maybe I'm not using the right search terms, but nothing useful is turning up when I search for the following:
"Software safety Qt GUI" or any permutation of that.

Thanks again for any helpful insights.

Comment: Very good question. One I've also failed to find any existing research on!

Comment: Take a lock at this site: [https://www.qt.io/functional-safety-and-qt] (qt safety)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the best info on Qt for research, contact Qt's leadership directly especially the public marketing contacts from the most recent Qt real-time announcement:

- Jessica Miller
  Wind River
  jessica.miller@windriver.com
- Katherine Barrios
  Digia / Qt Commercial
  Katherine.barrios@digia.com

These three people may be helpful too - you'll need to figure out their contact info.

- David Stone, Qt Communications Manager.
- Aron Kozak, Web and Community group.
- Hanne Linaae, Qt Education manager.

You can post your request in the Qt developer network forums.

Qt Developer Network Online Communities:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/OnlineCommunities

Qt Forums:
http://qt-project.org/forums

Comment: Good suggestion.  I posted to the forum (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15952/) and sent and email to the folks you recommended contacting.  Currently I'm awaiting a reply.  Unfortunately, the lack of responsiveness leads me to assume that no research has been performed to investigate the appropriate use of QT in RT Safety Critical environments.  That is unfortunate.